# WPF Textbox Element freezes when setting the text property to a large string

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uwp, textbox

I am currently developing an UWP app and I encountered a problem with the
TextBox WPF Element, which seems to have terrible performance when dealing with larger texts. Pasting a large text from the clipboard into the textbox works perfectly fine, but when I try to set the text programmatically it freezes the entire application:

```cs
textbox.Text = sb.ToString(); //Freezes or takes for ever
```

This is how I defined the textbox in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,70"/>
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this performance problem or are 
there any alternative text field elements I could use?

Comment: Any idea how long the string is?  I'd like to try and reproduce the issue because it doesn't seem to make sense why that's happening.

Comment: about 5000 characters are able to freeze the application for a considerable amount of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I've been able to get the time it takes to add the text to take up to 133 milliseconds is the highest I found.  That's a slight jitter; if I add 50K characters it takes about 1000ms which is noticeable but not that bad given the number of characters.

To perform the test I first made a view with:
`ProgressBar` to detect UI freezing / jitter.
`TextBlock` to show time in milliseconds it takes to add the text.
`Button` to start the adding of the text.
`TextBox` to add the text to.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page x:Class="Question_Answer_UWPApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <ProgressBar Name="progressBarAddingText"
                     IsIndeterminate="True" />

        <TextBlock Name="textBlockAddingTextTime" />

        <Button Content="Add Text"
                Click="ButtonClick" />

        <TextBox Name="textBoxAddingText"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Margin="0,0,0,70" />

    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Question_Answer_UWPApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async void AddTextAsynchronously()
        { 
            var text = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
                    stringBuilder.Append("X");

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            });

            stopwatch.Start();

            textBoxAddingText.Text = text;

            stopwatch.Stop();
            textBlockAddingTextTime.Text = $"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()} milliseconds";
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddTextAsynchronously();
        }
    }
}
```

In this test I got about 133ms but when I place the `StringBuilder` outside of the `Task` and use the `Task` just to build the `StringBuilder` (essentially allowing me to say `.Text = stringBuilder.ToString()` it takes about another 10 milliseconds.  Which means the `StringBuilder` isn't the bottle neck.  I don't believe the adding of the text to the `TextBox` is your bottleneck either.

With this test I feel that you should look in other locations for your bottleneck.  This should safely answer the question that adding text to the `TextBox` via code isn't time consuming.

Comment: hey thank you. you really helped me out here. the problem was the kind of characters i was writing and not the quantity. due to an error in my code i wrote all sorts of control characters etc.what had caused the problem. without you i would probably still be fixated on the thinking that the size of the text was the problem